# Many-to-Many field find record

Tags: django

I want to query the database and get the data of against id which have highest occurence in the database table.

```
 story table                            

 id  story_name   
 1         this is one                   
 2         this is two



 story_story_table

 id  story_id   
 1     1                     
 2     1  
 3     1  
 4     2 
 5     3
```

now id 1 have highest occurence. first find highest occurence then get data against this id. using django

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your current code and what's not working properly.

Comment: sorry brother. now i have edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the highest occurrence using django's ORM built in API.

```
unique_fields = ['story_id','story_name_id']

duplicates = (Model.objects.values(*unique_fields)
                                 .annotate(max_id=models.Max('id'),
                                           count_id=models.Count('id'))
                                 .filter(count_id__gt=1)
                                 .order_by())
```

This will gives repeated records as per given fields and to highest occurrence you can simply use `len(duplicates)`

**Edited:**

```
highest_occured = (Model.objects.values(*unique_fields)
                                 .annotate(max_id=models.Max('id'),
                                           count_id=models.Count('id'))
                                 .filter(count_id=models.Max(count_id))
                                 .order_by())
```

I hope this will be help full. :)

Comment: I have to do this in my view.py? is this code get the id which have highest occurence then I can query story model to get this story against is?

Comment: Yes, you can write this code where you need And Using this query you can get repeated records as we have mentioned in the filter that we want count_id__gt i.e. records count must be greater than 1.

Comment: and you should use this query on the model from where you want to calculate highest occurrence.

Comment: max_id=models.Max('id')     what is models it give error at this models varible

Comment: It should not give this error as this models is a built in annotate object. You should fire this code as it is.

Comment: NameError: name 'models' is not defined.   I fire this code as it si simple change mymodel name

Comment: I think you need to do import models as "from django.db import models"

Comment: duplicates = (Attendance.objects.values('cause')
                                 .annotate(max_id=models.Max('id'),
                                           count_id=models.Count('id'))
                                 .filter(count_id__gt=1)
                                 .order_by())      i have write this

Comment: and the output is :[{'max_id': 8, 'cause': 1L, 'count_id': 3}, {'max_id': 9, 'cause': 4L, 'count_id': 2}]

Comment: So can see the highest count which can be consider as highest occurrences.

Comment: I have edited the answer to get only highest occurrence record only.

Comment: thanks brother. now how I extract id=1 which have high occurence from duplicate

Comment: Try to get only highest occurrence by using models.MAX(count_id) in filter, also updated this in answer.